# Show that $S_{4}$ is a solvable group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to show that $ S_{4} $ is a solvable group. So I want to show that there is a $k \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $S_{4}^{k}= {I}$ (the k-th derived subgroup). What's the best way to show this, just calcuting these derived groups? Because it takes a long time to do it.

Comment: It doesn't take so long---rather than computing blindly, consider the cycle types of elements that appear in the first derived subgroup, then the second derived subgroup. The second derived subgroup is abelian but nontrivial, so the minimal solution is $k = 3$.

Comment: You can also use the fact that a quotient $G/H$ is abelian if and only if the commutator is contained in $H \lhd G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we look at the commutator of two transpositions, first. If they are disjoint, or equal, we just get $e$, so we won't bother looking at those. That means our two transpositions have exactly one element in common. So suppose it is:

$[(a\ b), (a\ c)] = (a\ b)(a\ c)(a\ b)(a\ c) = (a\ c\ b)(a\ c\ b) = (a\ b\ c)$.

This shows that $[S_4,S_4]$ contains every $3$-cycle, and thus must contain $A_4$.

On the other hand, every commutator is an even permutation, so $[S_4,S_4] = A_4$ (alternatively, $S_4/A_4$ is cyclic, thus abelian).

Computing $[A_4,A_4]$ is a bit more involved. We need to compute the commutators of:

Two pairs of disjoint pairs of transpositions

Two $3$-cycles

A $3$-cycle and a pair of disjoint transpositions (in both orders)

The first kind of commutator is clearly trivial; for example:

$(a\ b)(c\ d)(a\ c)(b\ d)(a\ b)(c\ d)(a\ c)(b\ d)$

$= (a\ d)(b\ c)(a\ d)(b\ c) = e$

The last kind is either trivial, or a pair of disjoint transpositions, being a conjugate of a disjoint pair of transpositions time a disjoint pair of transpositions or vice-versa. Convince yourself the latter actually happens, and we can obtain any disjoint pair of transpositions this way.

If the two $3$-cycles are not powers of each other (in which case they commute, and the commutator is $e$), they have $2$ elements in common, and:

$(a\ b\ c)(a\ b\ d)(a\ c\ b)(a\ d\ b) = (a\ b)(c\ d)$, while:

$(a\ b\ c)(a\ b\ d)(a\ c\ b)(a\ b\ d) = (a\ d)(b\ c)$.

This shows $[A_4,A_4]$ contains $V = \{e,(1\ 2)(3\ 4), (1\ 3)(2\ 4), (1\ 4)(2\ 3)\}$. Here, the commutators themselves are closed under multiplication, so $[A_4,A_4] = V$.

Alternatively, $A_4/V$ is abelian, so $[A_4,A_4] \subseteq V$, and $A_4$ is not abelian, and $V$ is a maximal subgroup, so $[A_4,A_4] = V$.

And now you are done, since $V$ is abelian, that is $[V,V] = \{e\}$.

Comment: why " If they are disjoint we get the identity"?

Comment: "every commutator is an even permutation" why ?

Comment: If two transpositions $s,t$ are disjoint, they commute, so we get: $[s,t] = sts^{-1}t^{-1} = tss^{-1}t^{-1} = tt^{-1} = e$.

Comment: Suppose $p$ is a permutation that can be written as $k$ transpositions, and $r$ is a permutation that can be written as $m$ transpositions. Then $[p,r]$ can be written as $k+m+k+m = 2(k+m)$ transpositions, and this is even.