# Why every commutator is an even permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading the solution of proving that $S_4$ is a solvable group here
[Show that $S_{4}$ is a solvable group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485774/show-that-s-4-is-a-solvable-group)

But I did not understand the statement " every commutator is an even permutation",could anyone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Consider the homomorphism $\pi : S_n \to \{\pm 1\}$ that assigns a permutation to its sign, and apply it to a general commutator $g h g^{-1} h^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

The sign homomorphism $\operatorname{sgn}:S_n\to C_2$ is onto a commutative group, so $\ker\operatorname{sgn}\supseteq[S_n,S_n]$.

Answer (score 3):

In elementary terms, if $g$ can be written as a product of $a$ transpositions, and $h$ can be written as a product of $b$ transpositions, then $g^{-1} h^{-1} g h$ can be written as a product of $a + b + a + b$ = $2 (a + b)$ transpositions.